# uninitialized constant {model}Controller::Spreadsheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

I am using the Spreadsheet class inside my Rails (v2.0.0) controller code as follows:

```
def run
  book = Spreadsheet.open '--file path'
end
```

and I get a "NameError: uninitialized constant {model}Controller::Spreadsheet" error.  The spreadsheet gem is loaded and I am able to execute this specific line in Rails Console.
When I added `require 'spreadsheet'` in the controller file as suggested in another Stackflow question I get the error 'unable to load module'. From my understanding of how GEM files should work, that is the only place I need to specify the gem. In my Gemfile I have `gem 'spreadsheet'` and I have run `bundle install`
So why is the spreadsheet gem not available to the controller code? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Spreadsheet in a Rails app no problem.

Are you really using Rails v2.0.0?

My app has to handle XLS and PDF files, so I have the following setup:

app > builders > documents  > xls_builder.rb

Then in xls_builder.rb

```
require 'spreadsheet'
module Documents
    module XlsBuilder

        def self.read_file path
            Spreadsheet.open path
        end
    end
end
```

When I want to open an xls file, I then just reference the Documents::XlsBuilder module and the methods inside.

Regards

Paul

Comment: Thanks for coming back. I duplicated your exact code. However, I still get the same error. I am calling the method in the following way: `book= Documents::XlsBuilder.read_file @rule.excel`.  In Rails (v4.2.3) console when I execute the same command, I get the following error `LoadError: cannot load such file -- spreadsheet
 from /Users/gt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@kb/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'` which suggests that Rails is having problems with trying to load the ` spreadsheet`  gem.

Comment: I am using Ruby 2.0.0, Rails (4.2.3) and spreadsheet gem spreadsheet-1.0.4.  I can call `Documents::XlsBuilder.read_file -path-` in Rails console but execution within the controller seems to make the module go AWOL.

Comment: Should be `book= Documents::XlsBuilder::read_file @rule.excel`. Code works! Thanks.